# SQL Select Highest Surge of Activity in period of time

Tags: sql-server, android-activity

I am working on a database dealing with information regarding red-light violations from the beginning of the year until present-day.

The table I'm working with is `Violations[TicketID, CameraID, DateOfViolation]`

I want to find a `CameraID` with the most amount of tickets serviced (which amounts to a new entry in `Violations`) in, say, the last 7 days.  If there is no activity in the last 7 days, I want `null` to be returned (i.e. **don't** open the range to be the last 14 days).

What is the command for this? I'm not sure how to even begin adding constraint for past 7 days. I am connecting to a **Microsoft SQL Server**.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. In the OP I mention that I'm not sure how to even begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 CameraID
from violations
where DateOfViolation >= dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
group by CameraID
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything. If I extend to 30 days (which should definitely return a result), still nothing is returned.